# Detecting whether number string or operator/letter string in PHP?

Tags: php, numbers

In PHP, how do I distinguish between a number as a string [0-9] versus an operator (+-*/) or letter [A-Za-z]?

I tried this, but intval also converts the type of nonnumbers to ints as well:

```
is_int(intval($somestr));
```

Is regex the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

> [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php#98037) gives true by f. ex. 1e3 or 0xf5 too. So it's not the same as [ctype_digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982645/detecting-whether-number-string-or-operator-letter-string-in-php/2982651#2982651), which just gives true when only values from 0 to 9 are entered.

Comment: Why leave a cheeky comment below my answer when yours isn't what he asked for?

Comment: Because I answered the question & then I saw yours. Using cheeky is cheeky! & it's recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [ctype functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ctype.php). E.g.:

```
$isNumeric = ctype_digit('123123');
```

Comment: Except yours is not. He asked how to detect numbers OR letters OR symbols. The is no `is_letter` or `is_symbol` functions like `ctype` has.

Comment: "How do I distinguish between a number as a string [0-9] VERSUS an operator (+-*/) OR letter [A-Za-z]?" from this I get what I answered!

Comment: These are both pretty useful, but this time, I'll use is_numeric().  ctype_digit() will come in very handy though.